# mod_wsgi on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi, amazon-lightsail

I want to install Apache server module mod_wsgi on (Server version: Apache/2.4.56) Amazon Linux 2023 a Lightsail Instance. I have python3.9 and I tried with rpm it's showing error - Problem: conflicting requests
nothing provides libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by mod_wsgi-3.4-12.amzn2.0.2.x86_64

Yum install command is unable to find package. pip install is also not working.

Tried with Source Code (mod_wsgi) but it showing error for - apxs2, perhaps it will require to install httpd-devel and I am supposed that it may affect my already installed httpd on which sites are published.

Upgrades are available - releasever=2023.2.20231018 & releasever=2023.2.20231026 Can upgrades fix it?

So please help me, how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. **RPM Error - Python 2.7 Dependency**:
   The RPM is for an older version of `mod_wsgi` that requires Python 2.7. Find an RPM compatible with Python 3.9, or compile `mod_wsgi` from source using Python 3.9.
2. **Yum Can't Find Package**:
   `mod_wsgi` may not be in the default repositories. Enable EPEL and try again:

   ```bash
   sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
   sudo yum install mod_wsgi
   ```
3. **Pip Install Not Working**:
   `mod_wsgi` is an Apache module, not a Python package, so it can't be installed with `pip`.
4. **Source Code Compilation Errors**:
   Install `httpd-devel` to get the `apxs` tool without affecting the current `httpd`:

   ```bash
   sudo yum install httpd-devel
   ```
5. **System Upgrades**:
   While updating may not directly fix `mod_wsgi` issues, it's a good practice:

   ```bash
   sudo yum update
   ```

After the update, try installing `mod_wsgi` again via `yum`.

Comment: Thanks for help!  It is Amazon 2023 AMI so as I know it does not support EPEL. I will try to find RPM compatible with Python 3.9.

Comment: I am stuck here -

[user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx opt]$ rpm -i python39-mod_wsgi-4.7.1-7.module_el8+639+3fcd10de.x86_64.rpm
warning: python39-mod_wsgi-4.7.1-7.module_el8+639+3fcd10de.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        python39-setuptools is needed by python39-mod_wsgi-4.7.1-7.module_el8+639+3fcd10de.x86_64
===
[user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx opt]$ pip3.9 install setuptools
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (59.6.0)

Comment: Also tried ...
[user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx opt]$  cd /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages
[user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx site-packages]$ python3.9
Python 3.9.16 (main, Sep  8 2023, 00:00:00)
[GCC 11.4.1 20230605 (Red Hat 11.4.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>>

[user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx opt]$  sudo yum install python3.9-setuptools
Last metadata expiration check: 1 day, 20:43:33 ago on Tue Nov 28 16:15:02 2023.
Package python3-setuptools-59.6.0-2.amzn2023.0.4.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

AL2023 does not ship mod_wsgi.  mod_wsgi-3.4-12.amzn2.0.2 appears to be the package from AL2.  Mixing packages from different OS major versions is a bad idea and will lead to a broken system.  The [amazon-linux-2023 GitHub repo](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023) accepts issue reports and has a package request template.  There has already been a [request for mod_wsgi](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/267).